# Schema Registry allowing weird avro schema change

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I’m setting a subject to `full_transitive` compat mode.
It contains a nested avro schema and schema registry is allowing some changes that seem to be breaking to me.
My schema contains this

```
.....
                            {
                                "name": "address",
                                "type": [
                                  "null",
                                  {
                                    "type": "record",
                                    "name": "AvroAddress",
                                    "fields": [
                                      {
                                        "name": "address",
                                        "type": [
                                          "null",
                                          {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "avro.java.string": "String"
                                          }
                                        ],
                                        "doc": "...",
                                        "default": null
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "name": "country",
                                        "type": {
                                          "type": "string",
                                          "avro.java.string": "String"
                                        },
                                        "doc": "..."
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ],
                                "default": null
                              }, 
...
```

As you can see here the `country` field doesn’t have a default value but the Schema Registry allows me to update its name.
Is it because it is contained itself within a nullable field ? How an old consumer would react to this ?
What am I missing here please ?

Comment: Clarify what you mean "change the name"... If you modify the `"name": "country"`, then you're effectively adding a new field, and removing `country`

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer
I'm modifying the `"name"` field indeed and the SR allows me to do so.
But as I understand I normally can't remove a field with no default value (which is the case for the country field)

Comment: That's what I can't understand, I was expecting the SR to tell me it's an unauthorized change.

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps this subject's compatibility was set different than then overall registry config? Or maybe because the overall address field is nullable, records that have a mandatory country field would yield null for the AvroAddress container record

Comment: Someone helping me in the Confluent Slack community is suggesting a Schema Registry version upgrade, for now I'm using 5.5.0 Docker Image Tag of Confluent Schema Registry

Comment: I Forgot to update here but upgrading the version solved the issue !